# Multiple AJAX requests to PHP from 1 client

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an app that sends multiple requests to PHP via jQuery.post and each one has different params. The PHP script is a request for data from eBay API and takes 1-3 seconds to complete. The AJAX requests from the client are sent out in rapid succession and then immediately requested again after complete or error.

What starts to happen is that PHP executes the oldest requests first and then proceeds to the newer ones. So request 1 is done within 1-3 seconds but request 25 is upwards of 12-20 seconds.

What can be done to mitigate these issues?

**EDIT:** Not sending so many requests at once is not an option. Each request is asking for specific information from eBay and needs to be as close to real time as possible.

**EDIT_2:** I'm aware that PHP processes the requests in the order that they're received and don't assume that this is incorrect behavior. My question is if it's possible to bypass this behavior and make PHP execute the script in parallel instead of series.

Comment: Don't sent so many Ajax requests at once?

Comment: Who is executing what? PHP is executing the request or Javascript?

Comment: I would expect php/the webserver to address the requests in the order they're received, but you seem to imply that this is incorrect. What would be correct? I have a feeling of what your going to say....but maybe you should draw us a timeline to make things crystal clear.

Answer (score 0):

(IMHO) The only thing you could really do is try and eliminate the extra requests. For example, If an ajax request is simply getting how much time is left on an auction, request it once and build a timer based off of the data returned so that way you don't have to keep sending the requests. Think outside of the box as much as possible. If you can grab the data once and emulate ebay's behavior on your end, you can save requests. Also, Look into an ajax push engine. You may be able to push some of that data to your app instead of pulling it. So if an item has ended, you can get that information without looping ajax requests.

Comment: I'm requesting newly listed items from eBay. So I can't emulate that since each request is a different search query. Can you recommend an ajax push engine?

Comment: Did some research.. it seems that ebay does not have one yet. Other options could be separating the load across multiple servers and php engines. You could try separating the load using different engines as well, so execute some using php, some using rails, some using python etc... this way you are emulating the parallel behavior you are looking for. Which API(s) are you using?